# Change predictive text language independently of keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, input-source

Can I change the language used for my iPhone's predictive text input independently of the layout of the keyboard?  I want French spelling suggestions but I still want to type on a QWERTY keyboard.  The iPhone is a 5S, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Settings → General → Keyboards.
2. If French is not in the list, add it using Add New Keyboard → French.
3. From the list of keyboards which have been added, choose French, then select the QWERTY layout.

   [image]

You can remove other keyboards you no longer wish to use by sliding them from right to left.